# Gain of CE with RE

Tags: bjt

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fFvuSu.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Here's how I calculate it:

$$Vo = (-gmVpi) \cdot RL$$

which I think is equal to VE (voltage across RE), so:

$$Vo = -VE~~~~(1)$$

I also think that VE is equal to:

$$VE = VI \cdot \frac{RE}{RE+Rpi}~~~~(2)$$

So I equate (1) to (2) which yields:

$$Vo = -(VI \cdot \frac{RE}{RE+Rpi})$$
$$\frac{Vo}{VI} = - \frac{RE}{RE+Rpi}$$

What do you think?

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE, Patrick and congratulations for figuring out CircuitLab and adding the schematic. The site supports MathJAX for your formulas. Start and end them with `\$` or to put them on their own line use `$$`. You'll be taken seriously because it will be legible.

Comment: Vo is not equal to -VE. A current source causes in general a voltage drop.

Comment: What's the actual question? What's the problem?

Comment: I am trying to calculate the voltage gain (Vo/Vi). Thanks!

Comment: I think the way you labeled Rpi is not ok. It looks to me that Vpi is the voltage across Rpi. The way you have it Vpi=Vi. And Vpi affects the value of the current source you have there.

Comment: @Mario...What's the drop across it? I am trying to get Av (voltage gain) and that current source seems to complicate things. I thought it was the current through RL.

Comment: @SixtoCabrera. You are right. I just didn't know how to show it using CircuitLab. Yes it's across Rpi. Is my way of finding the voltage gain accurate?

Answer (score 1):

You can't actually use the voltage divider equation there because there is more components in parallel with \$R_E\$. Now, the way I would do it is with KCL.

The voltage across \$R_{pi}\$ isn't labeled correctly in the schematic. \$V_{pi}\$ is actually, $$V_{pi}=V_I-V_E$$. Keep that in mind. You did get \$V_o\$ correctly, $$V_o=-g_mV_{pi}R_L $$ or the same as

$$V_o=-g_m(V_I-V_E)R_L$$

You can use KCL now to get an expression for \$V_E\$ and plug it into the \$V_o\$ equation. Using KCL:

$$\frac{V_I-V_E}{R_{pi}}+g_mV_{pi}-\frac{V_E}{R_E}=0 $$

Using the fact that \$V_{pi}=V_I-V_E\$, the previous equation becomes
$$\frac{V_I-V_E}{R_{pi}}+g_m(V_I-V_E)-\frac{V_E}{R_E}=0 $$

Solve for \$V_E\$. ASA (after some algrebra, I'll let you do that), you should arrive at:

$$V_E=\frac{R_E(1+g_mR_{pi})}{R_E+g_mR_ER_{pi}+R_{pi}}V_I$$

If you plug \$V_E\$ into the \$V_o\$ equation, you will obtain your \$\dfrac{V_o}{V_I}\$ equation.

$$V_o=-g_mR_L(V_I-V_E)$$

$$V_o=-g_mR_L\bigg(V_I-\frac{R_E(1+g_mR_{pi})}{R_E+g_mR_ER_{pi}+R_{pi}}V_I\bigg)$$

You can factor out \$V_I\$ from inside the parenthesis,

$$V_o=-g_mR_LV_I\bigg(1-\frac{R_E(1+g_mR_{pi})}{R_E+g_mR_ER_{pi}+R_{pi}}\bigg)$$

And from there, you could divide everything by \$V_I\$ and obtain:
$$\frac{V_o}{V_I}=-g_mR_L\bigg(1-\frac{R_E(1+g_mR_{pi})}{R_E+g_mR_ER_{pi}+R_{pi}}\bigg)$$

That's your gain which you could further simplify if you found a common divisor for what's inside the parenthesis. ASA, you get a simplfied expression, something like:

$$\frac{V_o}{V_I}=\frac{-g_mR_LR_{pi}}{R_E+g_mR_ER_{pi}+R_{pi}}$$
 If I didn't mess up somewhere that should be the answer, but at least you see how to approach something like this.

Comment: @ Sixto.Thanks! It is really helpful with thorough analysis. A quick question, if there's an ro (hybrid pi model) in parallel with gmVpi, would that make any difference? I purposely ignore ro to make things easier for me, but I am curious if there's a ro across current source in the same circuit if that would change the outcome?

Comment: It does change the result because the current through \$R_L\$ is no longer \$-g_mV_{pi}\$. \$V_E\$ is also going to be different.

Comment: @Patrick I found this link: http://doctord.dyndns.org/courses/textbooks/JegerBlalock/Pang/Lecture6.pdf 
On page 21 they solve the same thing I did and later on the include \$r_o\$. Hopefully it helps